# Rare binary dependent variable panel data

Tags: panel-data, binary-data, fixed-effects-model, rare-events

I have financial data for the 2013 to 2017 period. The dependent variable is binary (1 if firm does an IPO 0 otherwise) and rare (44 positive outcomes and 21,000 negative outcomes over the 2013-2017 period). Binary dependent variable is at time t+1 and independent variables are continuous (at time t). I know that we could use a panel logit or probit model in these cases. Using a fixed effects logit for panel data I usually have classification issues (model can predict correctly negative outcomes but not positive outcomes).

I would like to use a fixed effects model but taking into account the rare binary outcomes. Do you have an idea what type of model would be most suitable for this case ? (Poisson regression eventually?)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to call for competing time to event outcomes (IPO or bought or folding or etc.) allowing for the possibility of neither (I.e. still could end in many ways = censored).

Comment: Hi Björn ! Thank you for your answer. I understand that time to event outcomes would be useful to measure independent variables effect on time to IPO. What if I need to see the explanatory power of lagged continuous independent variables on the binary dependent variable ? Would the time to event still work ? Would the time to event as well be suitable for my distribution (high share of negative outcomes) ? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what problem there would be with using lagged continuous independent variables as a time-varying covariate in a time-to-event model. I don't think binary vs. time-to-event makes much of a difference with respect to difficulties in dealing with rare events - except if you cut time into lots of time-intervals and make them binary, then events become comparatively rarer.